# OnPropertyChange Firing Order

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have an application where you can select between different objects in a ListBox.  When you select an object, it changes the viewmodel for a control.  The control utlizes the Timeline Control from CodePlex, and because of this, I have the StartDate and EndDate for the timeline data bound to ViewModel.  When the ViewModel is changed out, I sometimes get an error:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: MaxDateTime cannot be less then MinDateTime
```

This only occurs when I go from a later date to an earlier date.  I am pretty sure that is due to the way the Properties are automatically updated to the view.  This is the relevant XAML.

```
MaxDateTime="{Binding Path=RecordingEnd}" 
MinDateTime="{Binding Path=RecordingStart}" 
CurrentDateTime="{Binding Path=CurrentDateTime, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

The ViewModel has this:

```
        private int myObjectIndex;
        public int MyObjectIndex
        {
            get { return myObjectIndex; }
            set { myObjectIndex = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyObjectIndex"); MyObject = MyObjects[myObjectIndex]; }
        }

        private MyObjectViewModel myObject=new MyObjectViewModel();

        public MyObjectViewModel MyObject            {
            get { return myObject; }
            set
            {
                myObject= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyObject");
            }
        }
```

Is there a way around this problem?  Is there a way to tell WPF which order the parameters within an object should be updated?

Update:
I ended up using a variation of @colinsmith's response:

```
public MyObjectViewModel MyObject {
    get { return myObject; }
    set 
    {
        myObject= new MyObjectViewModel();
        OnPropertyChanged("MyObject");

        myObject= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyObject");    
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming the three definitions are not in that order? And can you clarify "When the ViewModel is changed out" what you mean by "changed out"?

Comment: When you select an item from the UI it causes and update to the object?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you try changing the order you set the properties to CurrentDateTime= MinDateTime= MaxDateTime= ... the order probably matters...i.e. your date ranges are different on different models....when the model data is set into the properties...you need them to be valid WHILE it is updating the properties e.g. CurrentDateTime needs to be in the min/max range....and max needs to be bigger than mindatetime

Comment: I posted sample code to show how it is changed out when the selected index is changed

Comment: When I change the order, it gets the same error, but now when changing from an earlier to later date range.  It seems that I can only make this way work for one or the other higher to lower or lower to higher.

Comment: When swapping the model you need to either turn off the date validation while it's doing it, or you need to set the min/max to the full range inbetween the swap.

Comment: Is there a way I can do that in the data binding?

Comment: This sounds like the Timeline control could be implemented better, why doesn't it coerce the dates into acceptable values instead of throwing an exception, there's a reason the coerce functionality is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this:

```
public MyObjectViewModel MyObject            {
            get { return myObject; }
            set
            {
                myObject=null;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyObject");

                myObject= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyObject");
            }
        }
```

Comment: I've had to use a similar approach before - it ensures that any bindings get updated with the null value before the new value is applied.

Comment: If you look at my edited question, you will find that I had to set the object to an empty instance instead of null because of some of the other references to it.  This worked very well though.

Comment: @jle....Is that so you don't get Binding errors showing up in your Output Window while it's in the null state  ? Just a suggestion...you could define a "static" empty MyObject within your MyObject and point to that instead of creating a new one each time.

Answer (score 0):

You could either handle the fact that a min datetime can be updated before the max datatime and make something invalid (i.e. deferr setting the max or the min until both the max and min are updated).    That might be very error-prone.  Or, you can make the max and min the same value so they can only get updated at the same time.  e.g. instead of having `RecordingEnd` and `RecordingStart` have `RecordingSpan` that has both the max and min in it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by RecordingSpan?  The timeline control with the error is part of a library.